# How to set UIToolBarPosition Top or bottom

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitoolbar

To set UIToolBar background Image I use the below code.

```
UIToolbar *tool=[[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 100.0)];
[tool setTintColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
UIBarButtonItem *btn=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Load" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
[tool setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:btn]];
 UIImage *barImage=[[UIImage imageNamed:@"BarBg.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(27,0,27,0)];
[tool setBackgroundImage:barImage forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionBottom
              barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
 [self.view addSubview:tool];
```

This shows the following output

But question arises where is the purple colour background image, which I had set?

[image]

If I change the position top the output changes to

```
   [tool setBackgroundImage:barImage forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionTop
                  barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

This is what I expect, when setting background image.

[image]

So I don't have any clear idea when to use UIToolBarPositionTop or UIToolBarPositionBottom?

Comment: I can't find a question here

Comment: @Jonesy please check now

Answer (score 0):

In the Apple [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIToolbar_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/UIToolbarPositionBottom) is stated:

> UIToolbarPositionBottom: Indicates the toolbar is at the top of its
>   containing view.
>
> UIToolbarPositionTop:  Indicates the toolbar is at the bottom of its
>   containing view.

Definitelly this is a bit strange (UIToolbarPosition**Top** means at **bottom**...), but, thats the way it is...

Maybe it's easier to think of it as: That content is above (Top) of the toolbar in UIToolbarPositionTop